# Creating dnxhd mov with ffmpeg giving errors

Tags: ffmpeg, png, flags, mov

I'm trying to make a create a dnxhd mov with ffmpeg but can't seem to get the codec working.

I've created a 1920x1080 .png to convert into .mov format

#### My code: (python)

```
ffmpeg = "C:\\Users\\jared.glass\\Desktop\\mov_test\\ffmpeg_2012_04_02.exe"
images = "C:\\Users\\jared.glass\\Desktop\\mov_test\\Untitled.png"
output = "C:\\Users\\jared.glass\\Desktop\\mov_test\\dnx_hd_test.mov"
os.system(ffmpeg + " -i " + images + " -r 24 -s 1920x1080 -vcodec dnxhd -b:v 120m -an -y " + output )
```

#### I get the following error:

Incompatible pixel format 'rgb24' for codec 'dnxhd', auto-selecting format 'yuv4
22p10le'
[buffer @ 0000000001D0D950] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:rgb24 tb:1/1000000 sar:0/1 sws_
param:
[buffersink @ 0000000001D0DB50] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scale 0' be
tween the filter 'src' and the filter 'out'
[scale @ 0000000001D0DDE0] w:1920 h:1080 fmt:rgb24 sar:0/1 -> w:1920 h:1080 fmt:
yuv422p10le sar:0/1 flags:0x4
[dnxhd @ 0000000001D14740] video parameters incompatible with DNxHD
Output #0, mov, to 'C:\Users\jared.glass\Desktop\mov_test\dnx_hd_test.mov':
    Stream #0:0: Video: dnxhd, yuv422p10le, 1920x1080, q=2-1024, 90k tbn, 24 tbc

Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png -> dnxhd)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters
such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Anyone have any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNxHD codec only supports a small number of attribute (bit rate, frame rate, width, height, etc.) combinations. For your selected combination of 24fps frame rate and 1080p resolution, the bit rate should be 115M instead of 120M.

Comment: Thanks, after some research I managed to figure that out but you are correct and thanks for your answer :)